# Lenovo F9 turns off the screen - how to put it off

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2010

on my laptop Lenovo, F9 turns off the screen - word requires alt-F9 to update fields but only the screen turns black - particularly boring with cross references

Comment: Do you have a `Fn` button? This is generally found in the lower left, between the `Ctrl` and `Windows` keys or to the left of the `Ctrl` key. Try holding that down along with `Alt` + `F9`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way:

1. In the **BIOS** Setup Utility.
2. Open the **Configuration menu**.
3. Change the **HotKey Mode** setting from **Enabled** to **Disabled**.
4. Open the **Exit menu** and select **Saving Changes**.
5. Then restart the machine to see if the issue has been resolved.